# how to change value for option value between to methods

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

this option with value mudName.orgId for cascading and this is works fine
but i can't search when submit form do nothing this value must be change to mudName.orgName
the question is how to change this value from mudName.orgId to mudName.orgName after cascading

option is

```
            <select  [(ngModel)]="bankParams.mudName" class="form-control ml-1 myInput" style="width: 130px" id="mudName" name="mudName"
         > 
          <option  *ngFor="let mudName of moderyat" [value]="mudName.orgName" >
            {{mudName.orgName}}
          </option>
```

method on submit form

```
  getStudentBank() {
this.studentBankService
  .getStudentBank(
    this.pagination.currentPage,
    this.pagination.itemPerPage,
    this.bankParams
  )
  .subscribe((res: PaginationResult<StudentBank[]>) => {
    (studentBank: StudentBank[]) => {
      this.studentBank = studentBank;
    };
    this.studentBank = res.result;
    this.pagination = res.pagination;
  });
```

}

code for cascading

```
  goChangeEdarat(countryId: number) {
if (countryId) {
  this.studentBankService.getEdaratByOrgId(countryId).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.edarat = data;
    }
  );
} else {
  
}
```

}

Comment: please post codes instead of screenshots

Comment: ok sir done all

Comment: Its not clear for me what you want. You want to change the ```value``` of the option after form submit?

Comment: yes i want to change option value after submit from orgId to orgName because orgId need to cascade and orgName need to search

Answer (score 0):

You can set your object to option's value with `[ngValue]` attribute. So your selected value will be object not `orgName` or `orgId`.

```html
<select  [(ngModel)]="bankParams" class="form-control ml-1 myInput" style="width: 130px" id="mudName" name="mudName">
     <option  *ngFor="let mudName of moderyat" [ngValue]="mudName" >
              {{mudName.orgName}}
     </option>
</select>
```

Now you can get all members of selected object.

Comment: bankParams comes from api as mudName not object must get this error  http://localhost:5000/Student/edarat/3:%20Object   and also cascade don't work too becasue it must be orgId which used in filter